# Iframe in Tab Madness!

Tags: jquery, iframe, tabs

I've searched all over and have found possible solutions but they don't quite work how i need them to. I am really new to jQuery but I'm trying :-)

I have an iframe that sits in a Tab
( Tabs powered by jQuery)

In the third tab sits an iframe that holds a slideshow

My problem:

When I click on the third tab which houses the iframe all the controls appear, the carousel seems to be working, but ...no pictures!!!

Firefox helped me find what fixes the problem, now i just need to find a way to do fix it.

In Firefox when i right click on the iframe and go to This frame -> Reload Frame 
VOILA! Pictures are back!

Question:

Is it possible with jQuery to tell when the third tab is selected and to refresh a div which contains the iframe when that third tab is selected?

Tab Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(function () {
                    var tabContainers = $('div.tabs > div');
                    tabContainers.hide().filter(':first').show();

                    $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').click(function () {
                            tabContainers.hide();
                            tabContainers.filter(this.hash).show();
                            $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
                            $(this).addClass('selected');
                            return false;
                    }).filter(':first').click();
            });
    </script>
```

Test page can be found here: http://artitechture.com/blah/tabs.html

Any help would be appreciated...I want to learn!

Comment: which browser are you using, works fine in Firefox 3.5 on xp

Comment: I'm using Firefox 3.0.11 windows xp, the weird thing is that in IE7 its a similar issue. In IE one image displays but you can see the carousel going. 

Last night i found a little code of javascript that refreshes the iframe and it fixed the problem for both IE and Firefox.

I would hate to have it only work for some people and not for all. Is there good alternative to an iframe anyone can suggest?

Comment: The problem with the piece of code i used was that you needed to be on that tab as soon as the page loaded in order for it to work (a user would not know to do this, and its an inconvenience)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the iframe you have a doc ready method that tries to call the pngfix() plugin method however this has not been included within the iframe. This will not help.

Comment: Thanks for that! I forgot to remove that earlier before i posted the test page. I have removed the call to pngfix(), but as suspected that was not the solution.

Comment: I have added the iframe to the First tab as well as the Third so you can see that if its in the First tab it loads fine, its when you go to the Third tab that it just refuses to work.